# SOCP Complementary Slackness Condition Confusion

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

So I know that for an SOCP, the complementary slackness condition together with the cone constraints are:

$$ \mathbf{s}^{T}\mathbf{x} = 0$$
$$ s \underset{K}{\geq} 0 $$
$$ x \underset{K}{\geq} 0 $$

In trying to derive an interior point method, I see that the above is often written as:

$$ SX \mathbf{e} = 0$$

Where $\mathbf{e} = [1, 0, 0, \ldots, 0]^{T}$, $S = arrow(\mathbf{s})$ and $X = arrow(\mathbf{x})$. Ie:

$$X = arrow(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{bmatrix} 
t_{x} & \tilde{\mathbf{x}}^{T} \\
\tilde{\mathbf{x}} & t_{x} \mathbf{I} 
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$S = arrow(\mathbf{s}) = \begin{bmatrix} 
t_{s} & \tilde{\mathbf{s}}^{T} \\
\tilde{\mathbf{s}} & t_{s} \mathbf{I} 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where we denote $\mathbf{x}^{T} = [ t_{x} \; \tilde{\mathbf{x}}]^{T}$ $\mathbf{s}^{T} = [ t_{s} \; \tilde{\mathbf{s}}]^{T}$.

**Question:** **Why do we need to write the matrices $X$ and $S$ this way?**

**Note:** I understand that for other interior point methods, for instance in LP, we can just let $S = diag(\mathbf{s})$ and $X = diag(\mathbf{x})$ which means $\mathbf{e} = \mathbf{1}$ So why the difference?

**Note:** I also understand that $\mathbf{x} \underset{K}{\geq} 0$ iff $arrow(\mathbf{x}) \geq 0$ I think this is related, but I don't see how it fits here.

Comment: Are you maybe looking at the description of a solver that is intended for semidefinite optimization?

Comment: An example without arrow matrix is [the ECOS solver](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/ecos_ecc.pdf) (see formula (5)).

Comment: @LinAlg I am not looking at any solver, just looking at algorithms for SOCP IP. I am trying to build one myself. Eventually, yes, I would like to understand how to build SOCP solvers on dedicated embedded systems, but right now, I just need to understand the basic algorithms.

Comment: Do you have an example where this notation is used? ECOS does not use arrow matrices, so they are not required.

Comment: @LinAlg One example is in the book 'Practical Optimization' by Andreas Antoniou and Wu-Sheng Lu on page 493.

Comment: @LinAlg Another example is the the thesis of Magnus Aerblad entitled 'A Second Order Cone Programming Algorithm for Model Predictive Control'

Comment: @LinAlg That is on page 16 of the thesis.

Comment: Write out the value of $XSe$ by multiplying through. What do you see?